# time length of an mp3 file

Tags: python, mp3, media, duration

What is the simplest way to determine the length (in seconds) of a given mp3 file, **without using outside libraries**? (python source highly appreciated)

Comment: open the containing folder in Explorer bring up the play time column, screen shot, ORC, text search.... Submit to The Daily WTF /joke

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [pymad](http://spacepants.org/src/pymad/).  It's an external library, but don't fall for the Not Invented Here trap.  Any particular reason you don't want any external libraries?

```
import mad

mf = mad.MadFile("foo.mp3")
track_length_in_milliseconds = mf.total_time()
```

Spotted [here](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Dec/4/mp3lengths/).

--

If you really don't want to use an external library, have a look [here](http://ibofobi.dk/stuff/mp3/) and check out how he's done it.  Warning: it's complicated.

Comment: I agree with recommending the external library. I haven't used it (or Python for that matter). But I once tried to write, in C++ a program that could simply play MP3s. That didn't pan out, but I did get far enough in to determine the duration of the file. I thought about refactoring that code to ...

Comment: ... post here, but it's pretty darn convoluted. (And in C++, not Python). Not even remotely simple.

Comment: Just a heads up, it looks to me like it only works on certain platforms. The most recent version crashes on installing because it lacks one of its own setup files, which it recommends I generate by running a second file with linux commands in it.

Answer (score 11):

For google followers' sake, here are a few more external libs:

- mpg321 -t
- ffmpeg -i
- midentify (mplayer basically) see [Using mplayer to determine length of audio/video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497681/using-mplayer-to-determine-length-of-audio-video-file)
- mencoder (pass it invalid params, it will spit out an error message but also give you info on the file in question, ex $ mencoder inputfile.mp3 -o fake)
- mediainfo program http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en
- exiftool
- the linux "file" command
- mp3info
- sox

refs:

- https://superuser.com/questions/36871/linux-command-line-utility-to-determine-mp3-bitrate
- http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/139468
- [mp3 length in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993971/mp3-length-in-milliseconds)

(making this a wiki for others to add to).

and libs: .net: naudio, java: jlayer, c: libmad

Cheers!

Comment: of these ffmpeg and mpg321 also handle http links as file locations, unfortunately the latter automatically plays the file, but im perfectly happy with ffmpeg :)

Answer (score 8):

> > Simple, parse MP3 binary blob to calculate something, in Python

That sounds like a pretty tall order. I don't know Python, but here's some code I've refactored from another program I once tried to write.

**Note:** It's in C++ (sorry, it's what I've got). Also, as-is, it'll only handle constant bit rate MPEG 1 Audio Layer 3 files. That *should* cover most, but I can't make any guarantee as to this working in all situations. Hopefully this does what you want, and hopefully refactoring it into Python is easier than doing it from scratch.

```cpp
// determines the duration, in seconds, of an MP3;
// assumes MPEG 1 (not 2 or 2.5) Audio Layer 3 (not 1 or 2)
// constant bit rate (not variable)

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//Bitrates, assuming MPEG 1 Audio Layer 3
const int bitrates[16] = {
         0,  32000,  40000,  48000,  56000,  64000,  80000,   96000,
    112000, 128000, 160000, 192000, 224000, 256000, 320000,       0
  };


//Intel processors are little-endian;
//search Google or see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endian
int reverse(int i)
{
    int toReturn = 0;
    toReturn |= ((i & 0x000000FF) << 24);
    toReturn |= ((i & 0x0000FF00) << 8);
    toReturn |= ((i & 0x00FF0000) >> 8);
    toReturn |= ((i & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
    return toReturn;
}

//In short, data in ID3v2 tags are stored as
//"syncsafe integers". This is so the tag info
//isn't mistaken for audio data, and attempted to
//be "played". For more info, have fun Googling it.
int syncsafe(int i)
{
 int toReturn = 0;
 toReturn |= ((i & 0x7F000000) >> 24);
 toReturn |= ((i & 0x007F0000) >>  9);
 toReturn |= ((i & 0x00007F00) <<  6);
 toReturn |= ((i & 0x0000007F) << 21);
 return toReturn;     
}

//How much room does ID3 version 1 tag info
//take up at the end of this file (if any)?
int id3v1size(ifstream& infile)
{
   streampos savePos = infile.tellg(); 

   //get to 128 bytes from file end
   infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
   streampos length = infile.tellg() - (streampos)128;
   infile.seekg(length);

   int size;
   char buffer[3] = {0};
   infile.read(buffer, 3);
   if( buffer[0] == 'T' && buffer[1] == 'A' && buffer[2] == 'G' )
     size = 128; //found tag data
   else
     size = 0; //nothing there

   infile.seekg(savePos);

   return size;

}

//how much room does ID3 version 2 tag info
//take up at the beginning of this file (if any)
int id3v2size(ifstream& infile)
{
   streampos savePos = infile.tellg(); 
   infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

   char buffer[6] = {0};
   infile.read(buffer, 6);
   if( buffer[0] != 'I' || buffer[1] != 'D' || buffer[2] != '3' )
   {   
       //no tag data
       infile.seekg(savePos);
       return 0;
   }

   int size = 0;
   infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
   size = syncsafe(size);

   infile.seekg(savePos);
   //"size" doesn't include the 10 byte ID3v2 header
   return size + 10;
}

int main(int argCount, char* argValues[])
{
  //you'll have to change this
  ifstream infile("C:/Music/Bush - Comedown.mp3", ios::binary);

  if(!infile.is_open())
  {
   infile.close();
   cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
  }

  //determine beginning and end of primary frame data (not ID3 tags)
  infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
  streampos dataEnd = infile.tellg();

  infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
  streampos dataBegin = 0;

  dataEnd -= id3v1size(infile);
  dataBegin += id3v2size(infile);

  infile.seekg(dataBegin,ios::beg);

  //determine bitrate based on header for first frame of audio data
  int headerBytes = 0;
  infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&headerBytes),sizeof(headerBytes));

  headerBytes = reverse(headerBytes);
  int bitrate = bitrates[(int)((headerBytes >> 12) & 0xF)];

  //calculate duration, in seconds
  int duration = (dataEnd - dataBegin)/(bitrate/8);

  infile.close();

  //print duration in minutes : seconds
  cout << duration/60 << ":" << duration%60 << endl;

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for something I'm building right now, since I don't need VBR support. All I needed to change was the bitrate since it was assuming 56k when the files were 32k (output from LAME).

Answer (score 7):

simply use `mutagen`

```
$pip install mutagen
```

use it in python shell:

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
audio = MP3(file_path)
print audio.info.length
```

Comment: Best answer. It's easily installed with PIP, no other requirements, and it simply gives the information stored in the file's metadata

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at audioread (some linux distros including ubuntu have packages), https://github.com/sampsyo/audioread

```
audio = audioread.audio_open('/path/to/mp3')
print audio.channels, audio.samplerate, audio.duration
```

Answer (score 0):

You might count the number of frames in the file. Each frame has a start code, although I can't recollect the exact value of the start code and I don't have MPEG specs laying around. Each frame has a certain length, around 40ms for MPEG1 layer II.

This method works for CBR-files (Constant Bit Rate), how VBR-files work is a completely different story.

From the document below:

For Layer I files us this formula:

FrameLengthInBytes = (12 * BitRate / SampleRate + Padding) * 4

For Layer II & III files use this formula:

FrameLengthInBytes = 144 * BitRate / SampleRate + Padding

[Information about MPEG Audio Frame Header](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm)

Comment: I believe the length is 26ms.