# Using mplayer to determine length of audio/video file

Tags: shell

The following works very nicely to determine the length of various audio/video files:

```
mplayer -identify file.ogg 2>/dev/null | grep ID_LENGTH
```

However, I want to kill mplayer's output so I can determine the length of many files more efficiently. How do I do that?

Comment: can you state your answer in the form of a question, please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `MPlayer` source ships with a sample script called `midentify`, which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This is a wrapper around the -identify functionality.
# It is supposed to escape the output properly, so it can be easily
# used in shellscripts by 'eval'ing the output of this script.
#
# Written by Tobias Diedrich <ranma+mplayer@tdiedrich.de>
# Licensed under GNU GPL.

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: midentify.sh <file> [<file> ...]"
        exit 1
fi

mplayer -vo null -ao null -frames 0 -identify "$@" 2>/dev/null |
        sed -ne '/^ID_/ {
                          s/[]()|&;<>`'"'"'\\!$" []/\\&/g;p
                        }'
```

The `-frames 0` makes `mplayer` exit immediately, and the `-vo null -ao null` prevent it from trying to open any video or audio devices.  These options are all documented in `man mplayer`.

Answer (score 6):

FFMPEG can give you the same information in a different format (and doesn't attempt playing the file):

```
ffmpeg -i <myfile>
```

Comment: Is there a way of invoking this so that it doesn't complain about no output files? It works nicely, but that non-`0` exit code is annoying if you're trying to call it from another program. Also, Wheezy suggests using `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @Inaimathi: Yes, ``ffprobe <myfile>`` does that.

Answer (score 3):

There's another FF-way in addition to @codelogic's method, which doesn't exit with an error:

```
ffprobe <file>
```

and look for the duration entry.

Or grep for it directly in the error stream:

```
ffprobe <file> 2> >(grep Duration)
```

Comment: Why `error stream` in `ffprobe` ? `ffmpeg` produces the error.

Comment: @Time: `ffprobe` prints to the error stream although it does not exit with an error code. Not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0):

looks like there are a few other libs available, see [time length of an mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119404/time-length-of-an-mp3-file/5059165#5059165)

Answer (score -1):

Download your .mp3 file, play it with your Player (ex. Windows Media Player) and the player will show the total time at the end of play.

Comment: this action will prevent the user from running such tasks in automation, which is likely what he is trying to do.