# Getting size of an audio file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Given an audio file (mp3 or wav), is here a way to get the duration, size (in bytes) and other other attributes of the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file size FileInfo would be worth looking at

```
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(string filename);
long fileSize = file.Length;
```

This gets you the file size

and to get attributes like Hidden status. something like the following can get it

```
  if (file.Attributes & System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden == System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden)
  {
       // hidden file
  }
```

I second the NAudio library for finding the duration of a track [in seconds]

Answer (score 0):

For the duration, you will need a library. I just found this one on google. http://www.codeplex.com/naudio

As for file size look at the `System.IO.File` class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file size by writing `new FileInfo(path).Length`.
If you have it in a stream, you can simply write `stream.Length`.

To get other information, you'll need audio codecs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's aC++ answer from a similar SO post about how to do it without using a library.

[time length of an mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119404/time-length-of-an-mp3-file)

Although the author wanted Python code, he got something else usable. Maybe the logic is what you need.